# Is it right to talk about dynamic range on frequency domain?

Tags: frequency-response, frequency-domain, time-domain

I'm comparing three frequency response's plots from simulations and experiments and I observed that two of them look like clamped to a DC component, where the max dB value is i.e. 100 and the min is 40 dB, while on the third one the max is i.e. 120 dB and the min is 10 dB. I want to use the correct term to talk about these intervals.

I've used the term dynamic range to express an amplitude variation interval on **time domain**, but is it right to use it on **frequency domain** too?

Comment: so you would like to say that the first has a *"spectral dynamic range"* of 60 dB and the latter has a *spectral dynamic range* of 110 dB?  what might you want to do about holes in the spectrum?  like what if the output is from a notch filter and there are some frequencies where it's $-\infty$ dB level?  what would the dynamic range be for that?

Answer (score 1):

the dynamic range is the difference between the largest and the smalles value of a quantity can asume, so yes, you can have a dynamic range for the magnitud of your frequency components, I'm not aware if there's another terminology when dealing with the frequency domain. One thing to consider is not only the dynamic range of your signals but also the dynamic range of the variables you'rr using to store it and to calculate the frequency response, altough in the frequency domain (and specially when working with dB) it's not a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

However in audio, dynamic range is the difference between the least loud and loudest audible range, measured in db. In audio engineering, it wouldn‘t be correct to use dynamic range relating to amplitudes of single frequencies.

Not that it wouldn‘t be correct but rather because it could be misleading and lead to misinterpretations. I guess it also depends on the field ie. audio engineering, electrical engineering, applied physics, mathematics, etc.